# Timeout Connecting to SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2016 from SQL Server 2014 and since doing so a repository is getting a `EntityCommandExecutionException` with the InnerException of `{"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}` after ~15 seconds after executing the repo.

I can manually increase the timeout length in the model to fix this, but it seems rather odd since this repo was working fine prior to the SQL Server upgrade. The underlying database/model, size of the data we're retrieving, and server settings are also unchanged. Is there something related to using EF 6 & .NET 4.6.1 with SQL Server 2016 that I'm not taking into account?

Below is the code with a hardcoded connection string to see if there's anything in there that needs to be modified for SQL Server 2016 specifically.

**Model Constructor (w/ timeout amount increased as a workaround)**

```
public OperationsModel(string connectionString, bool lazyLoading = false)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.CommandTimeout = 500;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoading;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = lazyLoading;
    }
```

**Method**

```
public void Example()
    {      
        //X'ed out the server and database, but those are correct
        using (var uow = new ModelManager(new OperationsModel("data source=XXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXX;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\" providerName=System.Data.SqlClient")))
        using (var repo = new MyRepository(uow))
        {
            var test = repo.GetAll().ToList(); //Exception gets thrown here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it taking longer to actually retrieve the results or does it just seem like the timeout is lower?

Comment: It seems like the timeout is lower. If I run the underlying query in SSMS it's the same speed as before and there haven't been any index changes or anything that would impact the query's performance. It seems like something with EF is causing it to timeout faster, but I can't pinpoint if it's actually EF or SQL Server itself.